# How to run a job on the basis of pipeline variables in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

I am trying to execute a job on some pipeline variables. I have used 'rules' in my .gitlab-ci.yml file but getting the error "key may not be used with 'rules': only".
How can I do this?

```
build-dev:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
    - branches
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=="my-featured-branch"'
      when : never
```

Comment: It'd be better if you'd include a stripped down `.gitlab-ci.yml` and the full error message. Do I understand you correctly that you want to include a certain job only if some variable is set?

Comment: Yeah you got it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're receiving is literally what it says: you shouldn't use `only` with `rules` together in the same job.

Basically the reason is that this could lead into problems due to mixed behavior.

From the documentation:

> `rules` replaces `only`/`except` and they can’t be used together in the same job. If you configure one job to use both keywords, the GitLab returns a key may not be used with rules error.